# Relatively positioned container fully enclosing absolutely positioned children

Tags: css, css-position

I have some position:absolute elements inside a position:relative container.

Is there a way to make the container fully enclose its children?

E.g. if I give the container a background colour, I want to see the background color underneath all the absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: can you provide some code for us to see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noope, you'll have to give the parent some width and some height. I didn't fully understand CSS Floats until I read this article:

http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101